# VSCode Jest extension using the wrong version of Node

Tags: visual-studio-code, node.js

I am using the [VSCode Jest extension](https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest).

One of the features it gives you, is running your tests in the IDE and giving inline error messages.

[image]

The error it is giving me here `TypeError: this.children.flatMap is not a function` is the Jest tests running in the wrong node runtime - `.flatMap` is included in versions of node >11.

When I run Jest from command line, I also get this error, which I've fixed by adding a `.nvmrc` to my project, and using nvm to change the node version.

How do I tell Jest/VSCode to simillarly change its Node runtime?

Comment: One solution is to change the node version in terminal and start vscode with the `code` command. But this is a little annoying as I typically start VScode with a taskbar shortcut

Comment: was adding `.nvmrc` help? 
If yes could you add it as an answer?

Comment: @otong adding .nvmrc does not help, mine is already there and it still uses old node version

Answer (score 4):

You can add in you setting.json the next lines:

```
"jest.shell": "/bin/zsh",
"jest.jestCommandLine": "source ~/.zshrc && nvm use 14.15 && yarn test",
```

that works if you're using zsh

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sounds like you can also use `"jest.jestCommandLine": "source ~/.zshrc && nvm exec $* && yarn test"` if you have any nvm auto version switch enabled for your zsh/terminal, see https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest/issues/72#issuecomment-939224489

Answer (score 0):

This issue is tracked within the [`jest-community/vscode-jest#72`](https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest/issues/72). As per [this comment](https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest/issues/72#issuecomment-336821641), the best solution currently seems to be to update your system to use the Node version specified within your `.nvmrc` by default:

```
nvm alias default $(cat .nvmrc)
```

Obviously this is not ideal as it affects your entire system and will cause issues if you have multiple projects using different versions of Node.

Comment: This solution seems better https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest/issues/72#issuecomment-939224489